# Is it a good idea to use Rails 4.1 Beta in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Is it a good choice to use the beta in production?**

My Pro: I currently have to implement a lot of features in 4.1 manually or with a bunch of gems. Using 4.1 would really simplify that.

**Are there any cons?**

**Update**

Using 4.1 by itself is great -- but I ended up sticking with 4.0 because there are lots of gems that won't work with 4.1 right now. Unless you aren't using other 3rd party gems, probably wait for a while for production projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question: is a edge version raising up performance/security of your application?

So the words i'v trust so far at this question are from [rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/12/18/Rails-4-1-beta1/):

> In fact, we're already running beta1 in production for Basecamp, so you know it's been taking a good beating. This helped us catch a couple of performance regressions, and we've verified that everything is still spiffy fast on Basecamp.

Comment: that is what enticed me to use the beta as well -- since they're willing to use it for Basecamp.

Comment: @Hopstream so if its simplify your life, all specs are green plus we have proof from 37signals, then why not just to try it?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious con is that something you implement in production may break when Rails 4.1 goes out of beta. Your choices are to delay these features, or implement them using a bunch of gems and then re-do it all later, or risk damaging credibility with customers who are relying on your service to be stable. Personally, I wouldn't go with that last choice.

(Using any version of Rails for production at all is another issue entirely. Personally I prefer LAMP, but am using Rails now in my current job.)